# Cordova app for iOS with Plugins

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, swift

I am trying to create a cordova app for iOS. The same app we are using for android as well. I just tried to add the iOS plugin and launch the app. I have added below code in `CDVDevice.h`.

http://developmobilesoftware.blogspot.in/2013/12/the-unique-identifier-in-ios-app-udid.html

I am getting exception and my trace is as under :

```
+[CDVDevice uniqueIDForDevice] : unrecognized selector sent to class 0xf30c4
** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView: decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:delegate"<NSInvalidArgumentException> +[CDVDevice uniqueIDForDevice]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xf30c4
```

Please help I am new to iOS programming.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, editing CDVDevice isn't a good idea

But you can do two different things to fix your code:

change  `[devProps setObject:[[self class] uniqueIDForDevice] forKey:@"uniqueid"];`

to `[devProps setObject:[self uniqueIDForDevice] forKey:@"uniqueid"];`

or change `-(NSString*)uniqueIDForDevice`

to `+(NSString*)uniqueIDForDevice`

Explanation, class methods start with `+`, instance methods start with `-`, you have declared an instance method but you call it like a class method, so you can change the class method to  instance method changing the `-` to `+` or keep it as instance method and call it as an instance method just with `self` instead of `[self class]`

Anyway, as I said before, instead of editting the device plugin, you can use my identifier for vendor plugin

https://github.com/jcesarmobile/IDFVPlugin

```
window.IDFVPlugin.getIdentifier(function(identifier){ alert(identifier); },function(error){ alert(error); });
```

Comment: Thank you ! I am curious to know what was the issue with my code..
  [devProps setObject:[[self class] uniqueIDForDevice] forKey:@"uniqueid"];
this is how I am trying to access the method and have added it in device.js

Comment: then post the whole code you are using, not a link to a blog post

Comment: In - (NSDictionary*)deviceProperties of CDVDevice.h added a line 
[devProps setObject:[[self class] uniqueIDForDevice] forKey:@"uniqueid"];
and in device.js
me.uniqueid = info.uniqueid;

Comment: not in a comment, edit your question. Anyway, it isn't a good idea to edit CDVDevice